# WSO2 removes email when creating a user via SSO

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are creating users in WSO2 via multiple identity providers (mostly with ADFS backends). We are mapping the UPNs into the subject on ADFS side and expected to get user ids like user@domain on WSO2 side (using just-in-time provisioning. An example SAML response looks like this:

```
<Subject>
      <NameID>user@domain.com</NameID>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_d685e02e861d57cbf40c2a2af996f920" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-04T15:32:47.404Z" Recipient="https://ourdomain.de/commonauth"/>
      </SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
<Conditions>
      <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>ourdomain.com</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="Givenname">
        <AttributeValue>adfsFirsname</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="Lastname">
        <AttributeValue>adfsLastname</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="Role">
        <AttributeValue>domain-user</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeValue>test</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="username">
        <AttributeValue>test</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="mail">
        <AttributeValue>user@domain.de</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
</Conditions>
```

The problem is, that on WSO2 side we just get *user* as the userid and not the expected *user@domain*. Doesn't matter how we configure the mapping, the last @stuff gets cutted. Does anybody know, how to configure this, to get the complete *user@domain* as userid in WSO2?

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

By default, WSO2 products will take username as @. That's why the @stuff part of the username was removed. If you want to use email as the username you need to configure. [Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username) is the detailed documentation

Then the username will be treated as user@domain@tenentDomain. For the super tenant, you don't need to the @tenentDomain.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to create a custom-claim-dialog on ADFS side, which manipulates the claim to contain one more @-symbol. This forces WSOIS to do what I want. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works for now...